# Array inside a struct inside a matrix

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, structure

How i can pass (and change) this array P inside struct (that is allocated in a dinamic matrix, mtrix[][])

```
 typedef struct product 
{
 float P[5]; // I need to operate inside this array from my function. 
}PT;
```

this is my function

```
 int memo () // don't know how to declare /* i need to change the float of  a specific position of the array inside the specific structure */
{
 int x,y,pd;
 printf (" put x\n");
 scanf ("%d", &x);
 printf ("put y\n");
 scanf ("%d", &y);
 printf ("put pd\n");

 scanf  ("%d",&pd);
 printf ("insert new float\n"); /* i tried a lot of way but cant change nothing the code is incomplete because i really don't know how to change the specific place of the array inside the struct i selected */


 return ;
}
```

thank you from now and sorry for my bad english

Code Added - It's in italian- it's an exercize that i try to solve a lot of time- need to use it like a cash register  for more seller and for more days, but every seller have access only to five categories of product (and the thing selled are dayly added as an unique sum inside a different cell of the specific float) Hope to solve this problem i feel really stupid -.-

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>



int END = 0; Need this global to escape from the program


struct prodotti // prodotti tabaccheria un vettore di 5 per cinque categorie. 
{
 float P[5];
};


int main ()
{ 
    printf ("                   ************************************\n");
    printf ("                   *    Gestionale Cassa Tabaccheria  *\n");
    printf ("                   ************************************\n");


struct prodotti // prodotti tabaccheria un vettore di 5 per cinque categorie. 
{
 float P[5];
};

int v,d,z,i,pd,s,j,k, tv;
float tot;
struct prodotti **ptr;

printf("Quanti venditori vuoi gestire?\n");
scanf ("%d", &s);  

ptr=(struct prodotti**) calloc(s, sizeof(struct prodotti*));
if (ptr == NULL){
 printf ("Errore di allocazione\n");
 return 0;};

printf ("Di quanti giorni vuoi gestire le vendite?\n");
scanf ("%d", &d);

for (i=0; i<s; i++)
{
ptr[i] = (struct prodotti*) calloc(d, sizeof(struct prodotti) );
if (ptr[i] == NULL){
 printf ("Errore di allocazione\n");
 return 0;};
};


}
printf ("\n");
system ("PAUSE");

for (;;)
{
if (END==1){
;
 return 0;};
gestore_funzioni(ptr[0][0],d,s);
};
  return 0 ;  
};

int gestore_funzioni (struct prodotti** ptr, int d, int s)
{ 
  system("cls");
  int g;
  printf("\n\n");
  printf ("Cosa vuoi fare ora?\n");
  printf ("Immettere dei dati vendita = 1\n");
  printf ("Scovare dei dati di vendita specifici = 2\n");
  printf ("Trovare il migliore venditore per periodo di tempo = 3\n");
  printf ("Trovare prodotto che ha venduto maggiornemente nel periodo di tempo = 4\n");
  printf ("Uscire dal programma = 5\n");

 do {
 fflush (stdin);
 scanf ("%d", &g);
} while (g<0||g>5);

if (g==1){memo(ptr,d,s);}; // I ACCESS to MY function from THIS 
if (g==2){visualizzatore(ptr,d,s);};
if (g==3) {best_seller(ptr,d,s); };
if (g==4);//{ /*best_product(ptr[0][0],d); };*/best_seller(ptr[0][0],d); };
if (g==5){uscita();};

return ;
};


 memo ()
{
 int j,k,pd,i;


 printf (" Immetti il codice del venditore\n");
 scanf ("%d", &k);
 printf ("Di quale giorno vuoi memorizzare le vendite?\n");
 scanf ("%d", &j);
 printf ("Immetti il codice prodotto\n");
 // codici_prodotto();
 scanf  ("%d",&pd);
 printf ("Inserisci il venduto in Euro\n");
 scanf ("%f", ptr[k][j].P[pd]);

 printf("%.2f", ptr[k][j].P[pd]);

 return ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is not so clear. You create an instance of the structure as:

```
PT yourArray;
// you can now insert the values;
int i;
for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
  printf("Enter the element %d", i+1);
  scanf("%f", yourArray.P[i]);
}
```

This way you can enter the values in the array.
Similarly, you can modify the i th element by just assigning a certain value or expression:
    yourArray.P[i] = ... // some expression or value

Answer (score 0):

With...

```
mtrix[x][y]->PT->P[i];
```

you can access to the P member.

So let's say that you want to add a float on P[0] which is in PT and this is inside mtrix[0][0], you could do this:

```
printf ("insert new float\n");
scanf ("%f", &mtrix[0][0]->PT->P[i]);
```

Comment: doesn't work... how i can pass my matrix (with structure inside and array inside that structure) to a function?

Comment: Can you paste all your code?, then it would be easier for me to see what's wrong.

Comment: posted - sorry most part is in italian but i write an introduction to explain what i need to do.